# How do I access an array content using {{this}} inside a Handlebars loop?

Tags: handlebars.js

I am currently using [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to dynamically populate some panels. In one of them, I feel the need of repeating a given task.

```js
// Add a looping helper for Handlebars
Handlebars.registerHelper('repeat', function(nFrom, nTo, oBlock) {
    var sResult = '';
    for (var i=nFrom; i < nTo+1; i++)
        sResult += oBlock.fn(i);
    return sResult;
});
```

```html
{{#if oSomeObject}}
<ul>
    {{# repeat 1 2}}
    <li>{{../oSomeObject.aSomeProperty[{{this}}]</li>  <!-- Does not work (because of nested curlies) -->
    <li>{{../oSomeObject.aSomeProperty[this]}}</li>  <!-- Does not work -->
    {{/repeat}}
</ul>
{{/if}}
```

Is there any known way for me to access my array's content within my `repeat` block ?

Comment: I'd guess that replacing your `repeat` helper with something that could take the `oSomeObject.aSomeProperty` array as an argument would be your best bet, basically a general purpose for-loop helper of sorts.

Comment: I was looking for some neater way to do it. But I guess that'll do it. Thanks, feel free to write down an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('myHelper', function(object, nFrom, nTo, oBlock){
    var sResult = '';
    for(var i=nFrom; i<nTo+1; i++)
        sResult += oBlock.fn(object[i]);
    return sResult;
});
```

or, if you want to iterate though **all** of the `oSomeObject`'s

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('myHelper', function(object, oBlock){
    var sResult = '';
    for(var i=0; i<object.length; i++)
        sResult += oBlock.fn(object[i]);
    return sResult;
});
```

then you can call it with:

```
{{#myHelper oSomeObject}}
    <li>{{aSomeProperty}}</li>
{{/myHelper}}
```

this is in effect the same as handlebars' `each` block helper, so you could use just:

```
{{#each oSomeObject}}
    <li>{{aSomeProperty}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

[source](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#iterators)